# Incorrect type. Expected in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to navigate to windows partition.

```
Incorrect type. Expected "string | array"
```

my script:

```
  script:
    - sshpass -p "****()" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ***@**** "F: & cd server/htdocs & git pull"
```

the error is for "F:"

Comment: solved. To use commands that contain a colon, you should wrap the whole command in single quotes. You might need to change existing single quotes (') into double quotes ("):


https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#:~:text=Use%20special%20characters%20with%20script,-Sometimes%2C%20script%20commands&text=For%20example%2C%20commands%20that%20contain,%E2%80%9Ckey%3A%20value%E2%80%9D%20pair.&text=You%20can%20verify%20the%20syntax%20is%20valid%20with%20the%20CI%20Lint%20tool.